# split string using special characters using java

Tags: java

I have a string split by `$#`

```
String SCBHL_NEW=" abc$#def$#ghi"
```

But, when I use it using `java`

```
String[] scbCCNewArray = SCBHL_NEW.split("\\$#");
```

It doesn't allow me.. Is it the right way?

Comment: In Java you have to use `\\$#`

Comment: @TheLostMind, That is not working.. It throws me an error Identifier or code block expected

Comment: Show us your *complete code*.

Comment: Its already there in the question. That line itself throws me an error.

Comment: Where are you putting this line --> `String[] scbCCNewArray = SCBHL_NEW.split("\\$#");` ?. Is it inside a method or block?..U think  it is outside any method or block

Comment: That is inside a block

Comment: What error are you getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regex is wrong $ special character. In addition, it has special behaviour in regex. That's why you need to escape both of them by \\

Refer the following code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String SCBHL_NEW="abc$#def$#ghi";

    String scbCCNewArray [] = SCBHL_NEW.split("\\$#");

    for(String str: scbCCNewArray){
        System.out.println(str);
    }

}
```

**Output:**

```
abc
def
ghi
```

Comment: Thanks Saint. Even that is not working. Not sure why? Basically I'm taking that string from the config entry.

Comment: Check the value of SCBHL_NEW which you get after fetching it from config.

Comment: Nope. `#` is not a special character in java regex